# Excel - Duplicate Cells in a Column Individually

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with unique numbers that I need to work. First, I'm needing to format the existing column so that each number is shown 13 times. I've attached a basic example of the principle. Is there an easier way to do this than just inserting rows and copying the number down? It's going to be across hundreds of numbers. Running O365

[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this worked perfect, mind putting it as an answer so I can select it as solved?

Comment: or use `LAMBDA()` Function in **Defined Name Manager** as `DUPLICATEfx` or any other friendly name you like to use, !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may ***try*** any one of the either,

For **All Versions Of Excel**,

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$5,INT((ROW()-1)/13)+1)
```

For **Excel 2021** & **O365** Users,

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$5,INT(SEQUENCE(13*A5,,0,1/13)+1))
```

Or, Using `LET()` Function

```
=LET(a,A1:A5,b,A5,INDEX(a,INT(SEQUENCE(13*b,,0,1/13)+1)))
```

Or, Use a `LAMBDA()` Function to create a custom, reusable function and refer them by a friendly name,

```
=DUPLICATEfx(A1:A5,A5)
```

Where,

```
DUPLICATEfx =LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(a,INT(SEQUENCE(13*b,,0,1/13)+1)))
```

`LAMBDA()` Function used in **Name Manager** with a **Defined Name** as `DUPLICATEfx` with syntax as

```
=DUPLICATEfx(a,b)
```

Or, Use `TOCOL()` Function,

```
=TOCOL(INT(SEQUENCE($A$5*13,A1,0,1/13)+1))
```

Or, Use `LET()` with `TOCOL()`

```
=LET(a,A1,b,A5,TOCOL(INT(SEQUENCE(b*13,a,0,1/13)+1)))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Nice. Too many ways...

Comment: @Harun24HR Dada, created one, then thought why not try other ways, may be useful, so just following your footsteps. Thank you so much!